# Multiplicity constraint violated. The role '...' of the relationship '...' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I'm getting the following error from my DbContext: "Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'MyEntity' of the relationship 'MyModel.FK_ChildEntities_MyEntities' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1."

using ASP.NET, Entity Framework 4

Working with a detached entity

The error happens the second time I try to reattach an entity to the dbcontext. The scenario is an unsuccessful save followed by a reattempt.

I have a detached entity in session. The user changes properties in a form, add things, removes things and finally clicks save. I get an attached copy of the entity from a new instance of the dbcontext, apply changes from the detached entity to the attached entity, validate, find an error and abort. The user changes whatever and saves again.

On the second save, the whole save process repeats, only this time it all goes to hell. Pretty much everything is duplicated, causing one error or another or all of them. Values from views and lookup tables that are only supposed to be references are created new and reassigned id's. Most of those issues I've been able to resolve, but I'm left with the multiplicity error. Child elements are being created as exact copies of other child elements, down to the unique id, only in the Added state. Or, if I reference certain properties, instead of cloning an unmodified child, it drops the new one. Either way, none of the code is executing as it did the first time around.

I'm discarding the instance of the dbcontext and the attached entity each save attempt. I thought that would be enough to revert any changes but something must be sticking around. The only thing not discared or reset is the detached entity, which is in session, but I dont make any changes to it. At least not directly.

The code (very simplified) is something like this:

```
void Save()
{
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
   // detached entity from session
   MyEntity detachedEntity = (MyEntity)Session["DetachedEntity"];

   // attached entity from context
   MyEntity attachedEntity = context.MyEntities.Single(x=>x.id == detachedEntity.id);       


   // <remove children representing lookup table elements from detachedEntity to prevent duplicates>
   // <remove children representing view elements from detachedEntity to prevent duplicates>


   // <apply changes from detachedEntity to attachedEntity>


   // <add new children>
   // <remove deleted children>
   // <update modified children>


   // <set entity state to unchanged on view and lookup elements of attachedEntity to ensure no duplicates...>


   // <validate>


   if (errors.count>0)
     // <report errors>
   else
     context.SaveChanges();
}
}
```

as an example, this generates a multiplicity error:

```
// represents first save:
    using (var context = new MyContext())
    {
       // detached entity from session
       MyEntity detachedEntity = (MyEntity)Session["DetachedEntity"];

       // attached entity from context
       MyEntity attachedEntity = context.MyEntities.Single(x=>x.id == detachedEntity.id);       

       int debug1 = context.ChangeTracker.Entries<ChildEntity>().Count(); // debug1 == 0;

       attachedEntity.ChildEntities.Add(detachedEntity.ChildEntities.First());

       int debug2 = context.ChangeTracker.Entries<ChildEntity>().Count(); // debug2 == 1;

    }

// represents second save:
    using (var context = new MyContext())
    {
       // detached entity from session
       MyEntity detachedEntity = (MyEntity)Session["DetachedEntity"];

       // attached entity from context
       MyEntity attachedEntity = context.MyEntities.Single(x=>x.id == detachedEntity.id);    

       int debug1 = context.ChangeTracker.Entries<ChildEntity>().Count(); // debug1 == 0;

       attachedEntity.ChildEntities.Add(detachedEntity.ChildEntities.First());

       int debug2 = context.ChangeTracker.Entries<ChildEntity>().Count(); // multiplicity error;

    }
```

Answer (score 24):

somehow the dbcontext remembers what objects were added to it. if the exact same object shows up twice, it... blows

instead of adding child entities from my detached entity to the attached one, i should've been creating new copies of each child

```
ChildEntity detachedChild = detachedEntity.ChildEntities.First();
attachedEntity.ChildEntities.Add(new ChildEntity { 
   propertyA = detachedChild.propertyA,
   propertyB = detachedChild.propertyB
});
```

instead of

```
attachedEntity.ChildEntities.Add(detachedEntity.ChildEntities.First());
```

Comment: so it will create a new `ChildEntity` and adds it to `ChildEntities Table` and then makes the relationship

Comment: This happened to me when my `attachedEntity` (`MyEntity`) had a collection of `ChildEntity`, but my `ChildEntity` model had no collection of `MyEntity`. But I wanted to keep only one instance of the `ChildEntity`, so when I added the collection of `MyEntity` to `ChildEntity`, I could use `attachedEntity.ChildEntities.Add(detachedEntity.ChildEntities.First());`

Comment: @Reuben: The problem with that last line is, if you have lazy loading enabled, it will load all ChildEntities for that attachedEntity. Definitely not very efficient.

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that detachedChild.parent should be assigned attachedParent.

```
foreach(var detachedEntity in detachedEntities)
{
     attachedEntity.ChildEntities.Add(detachedEntity); 
     detachedEntity.ParentEntity = attachedEntity;
}
```

Comment: THIS. You would think that attaching a child to a new parent would make it obvious who the real parent is but NO. Thanks, this is the solution.

Comment: THANK YOU! this solved my problem. EF Y U be like that?

Answer (score 4):

**What you are trying to do is something like:**

```
ChildEntity childEntity = new ChildEntity()
{
  //do mapping or provide data EXCEPt THE PRIMARY KEY
}

foreach(ParentEntity parentEntity in parentEntities)
{
    parentEntity.Add(childEntity);
}

_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

**Result**

```
Multiplicity constraint violated. The role '…' of the relationship '…' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1
```

**The reason of the error message is**

that everytime the _dbContext adds the childEntity  to some parentEntity, it sets the generated primary key to the childEntity, so in the second loop of the foreach the primary key will be duplicated

**The fix is - Method #1 - for simple scenarios**

```
foreach(ParentEntity parentEntity in parentEntities)
{
    //Make a new object every time
    ChildEntity childEntity = new ChildEntity()
    {
      //do mapping or provide data EXCEPt THE PRIMARY KEY
    }

    parentEntity.Add(childEntity);
}

_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

**The fix is - Method #2 - for complex scenarios**

```
using YOUR_PROJECT.ANY_FOLDER.DeepCopyExtensions;    

ChildEntity childEntity = new ChildEntity()
{
  //do mapping or provide data EXCEPt THE PRIMARY KEY
}

foreach(ParentEntity parentEntity in parentEntities)
{
    //makes a copy of the childEntity object and pass it to the _dbContext, after saving each copy will be separated and the original object childEntity wont be touched 
    parentEntity.Add(DeepCopyByExpressionTrees.DeepCopyByExpressionTree(childEntity));
}

_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

**What is this method "DeepCopyByExpressionTrees.DeepCopyByExpressionTree(childEntity)" ?**

Check this project [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1111658/Fast-Deep-Copy-by-Expression-Trees-C-Sharp), download the source code, and only include the class file "DeepCopyByExpressionTrees.cs" to your project as a helper class and start using it any where.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to inspect the properties of the object you are trying to add. In my case it was mistakenly referencing the same invalid object on each add which it didn't like and thus threw the same error you have here.

Answer (score 0):

**EF 6 Update**

For me setting object state to added worked on sounds logical also

```
ChildEntity detachedChild = detachedEntity.ChildEntities.First();
var newChild = new ChildEntity { 
   propertyA = detachedChild.propertyA,
   propertyB = detachedChild.propertyB
});

// Mark all added entity entity state to Added
 attachedEntity.ChildEntities.Add(newChild );
                        db.Entry(newChild ).State = EntityState.Added;
```

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/update-one-to-many-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this error when I had navigation properties that had not been set or navigation properties that belonged to the wrong  Code First DBContext

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by making the child collections in the parent entity virtual. This allows one to easily Update the entity when its child collections don't change, which, for me, was most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but mine arose from a `AsNoTracking()` after my query.

I had something like this

`var myObject = dbContext.GetRepo<myType>().Query().AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault()`

And then later on I use that object to set anther object.

`var myChild = new Child { parent = myObect }`

and apparently EntityFramework tries to create a brand new object and hence causes a multiplicity error.