# Multiplicity constraint violated Entity framework 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orm, entity-framework-6, relational-database

I have something which i don't understand. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034003/multiplicity-constraint-violated-entity-framework-5) is a similar case like mine.
I have BaseEntity, Product, Supplier, Contract and a ProductSupplierForContract Entities, all inherit from BaseEntity.

Base Entity:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    // other properties that are not entities by themself
}
```

Product Entity:

```
[Required]
public ICollection<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }

[Required]
public ICollection<ProductSupplierForContract> ProductSupplierForContracts  { get; set; }

public  ICollection<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }
```

Supplier Entity:

```
public ICollection<ProductSupplierForContract> ProductSupplierForContracts  { get; set; }
public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

ProductSupplierForContract Entity:

```
public string ProductnumberValue { get; set; }    

public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
public int Supplier_Id { get; set; }

public Product Product { get; set; }
public int Product_Id { get; set; }

public Contract Contract { get; set; }
public int? Contract_Id { get; set; }
```

Contract Entity:

```
[Required]
public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
public ICollection<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
public ICollection<ProductSupplierForContract> ProductSupplierForContracts { get; set; }
```

Following scenario must be possible and allowed:
**1 Contract can hold multiple instances of 1 product BUT from a different supplier**.
Therefore i created the ProductSupplierForContract (PSFC) Entity which would hold this relation of *1product-1supplier-1productnumber (value) -1contract* .

When i edit 1 existing product that already has 1 PSFC instance, and add another instance of PSFC holding another PK, ProductId & SupplierId, i get this error:

```
{"Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'ProductSupplierForContract_Product_Target' of the relationship 'ContractCare.Models.ProductSupplierForContract_Product' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1."}
```

I don't get why because isn't it so that i can have:

```
PSFC 1 
PK 1
ProductId 1
SupplierId 1

PSFC 2
PK 2
ProductId 1
SupplierId 2
```

Why should i (like described in the linked post above) have a many to many relation  PSFC on Products?

Thank you for any feedback!
Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending on the link that [Aparna Gadgil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10706711/aparna-gadgil) provided, one of the comments posted by [Arturo Hernandez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/937703/arturo-hernandez) resolved the error that i had so i am going to mark this solved since my original issue was the error.

**Quote:**

> The problem is that detachedChild.parent should be assigned
>   attachedParent.

```
foreach(var detachedEntity in detachedEntities)
{
 attachedEntity.ChildEntities.Add(detachedEntity); 
 detachedEntity.ParentEntity = attachedEntity;
}
```

In my case, i had to attach the parent entity (product we are updating) to the **ProductSupplierForContract.Product**. Creating the new entity like suggested in the answer was already the case for me, and other things like attaching it and so on didn't fixed it for me.

Since i didn't post any code on how i was performing this action this wasn't very helpful to be able to help me and i will surely try to be more specific in the future :).

Kind regards and thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Following link might help you more in this problem!

1. [Multiplicity constraint violated. The role '...' of the relationship '...' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885561/multiplicity-constraint-violated-the-role-of-the-relationship-has-m)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Links break and the answer becomes worthless later. Please include some context. And see how to make a [good answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question).